# Getting Error Aborted (core dumped) in Node Version 8.17.0 with Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a script, in which I am executing a firebase query from a loop.
Here is the code

```
console.log("20")

if (lastCaptureData) {
    result = await app.database.collection(configurations.FIRESTOREAPP.USER)
        .where(actionObject[action].searchKey, '>=', startTimeStamp)
        .where(actionObject[action].searchKey, '<', endTimeStamp)
        .limit(limit).startAfter(lastCaptureData).get();
} else {
    result = await app.database.collection(configurations.FIRESTOREAPP.USER)
        .where(actionObject[action].searchKey, '>=', startTimeStamp)
        .where(actionObject[action].searchKey, '<', endTimeStamp)
        .limit(limit).get();
}

console.log("32");
```

In node version 8.16.0 this Code works fine.
But in node version 8.17.0 not on every loop cycle but at some cycle it gives me error as follows, and code terminates. That means, it prints 20 but it does not print 32,
I am not telling that every time I face this error, I face this error 3/10 times.

[image: Error I am getting]
Is it the memory leak issue ??

I just want to know why this is happening in Node 8.17.0, and working fine with Node 8.16.0.
Please Help!

Comment: Do you mean to use http 2.0?

Comment: I am just a learner, I don't know why it is coming, can you please tell, why is it so?  @CristianTraìna

Comment: Could you include the code that is performing the loop?